# Getting uncaught exception while trying to swtich over the tab. Tab is not a function

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

i want to switch over the tab while getting success message.but it throwing tab is not a function exception.
`

```
<script>
    var message = "<%=username%>";
    if(message !=null && message == "registrationSuccess"){
        alert("1");
        $('#myTab a[href="#login"]').tab('show');
    }
</script>`
```

Comment: these are my tabs

Comment: <ul class="tab-group" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>

Comment: Can you give full stacktrace?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function this the error it throwing browser..@user7294900

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of this mysterious `tab` function, especially the framework you use, I'd guess jquery...(also I don't know why jsp, and spring-mvc tags are used in this question...)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Jquery,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
 .tab{
  background-color: red;
 }
 .active{
  background-color: blue;
 }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

     var message = "registrationSuccess";

  $('#signup').on('click', function(){
   console.log($('#signup'));
   if(message == "registrationSuccess"){
    $('#signup').parent().addClass("tab").removeClass("active");
    $('#login').parent().addClass("active").removeClass("tab");
   }
  });
    });
</script>
 <ul class="tab-group" id="myTab"> 
  <li class="active">
   <a id="signup" href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
  </li> 
  <li class="tab">
   <a id="login" href="#login">Log In</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I have hardcoded the message variable and created the class active and tab as color only for test purpose, replace it with your values and this should work.